# Is there a way to configure health checks to an ECS service without a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have an ECS Cluster with 2 ECS Services (1 app-controller, 1 app-event-processor). Is there a way to get health checks on both while API traffic only goes to `app-controller`? I realize health checks normally come from the load balancer but if I configure the load balancer to hit `app-event-processor` then API traffic also starts flowing to `app-event-processor` which is undesirable since I want that to handle only messages from SQS for example.

Comment: ECS services have health checks separate from the load balancer. They are defined in the task definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @jordanm mentioned in their comment ECS does provide a built in [health-check mechamism](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_HealthCheck.html) that is orthogonal (and in addition) to the "outside" LB health-check.